# Multiple levels of multiline in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to be able to use a multiline filter, and then another multiline in a deeper level.

To be more exact, I want to have a java exception stack trace for example:

```
2014-06-20 Some-arbitrary-log
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
```

And then, after that, combine a couple of those together like so using another multiline and throttle:

```
2014-06-19 Some-arbitrary-log
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
2014-06-20 Some-arbitrary-log
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
```

My filter looks like so:

```
filter {
    if [type] =~ /test.+
    {
        multiline {
            pattern => "(^.+Exception.*)|(^\tat.+)"
            negate => false
            what => "previous"
        }
        if ("multiline" in [tags]) {
            mutate {
                add_field => [ "ERROR_TYPE", "java_exception" ]
            }
        }

        if ([ERROR_TYPE] == "java_exception") {
            throttle{
                key => ".*"
                period => 10
                before_count => 2
                after_count => -1
                add_tag => "throttled"
            }

            if ("throttled" not in [tags]) {
                multiline {
                    pattern => ".*"
                    negate => false
                    what => "previous"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The first level of just having one stack track trace works. 
As in, this works as intended:

```
    multiline {
        pattern => "(^.+Exception.*)|(^\tat.+)"
        negate => false
        what => "previous"
    }
    if ("multiline" in [tags]) {
        mutate {
            add_field => [ "ERROR_TYPE", "java_exception" ]
        }
    }
```

Combining multiple stack traces, however, doesn't work. The output I use is as so:

```
output {
    if [ERROR_TYPE] == "java_exception"{
    stdout {codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "logstash"
    }
    }
}
```

However, there are no combined stack traces. And all of them have the tags "throttled".

To check if there are any non-throttled, I did:

```
output {
    if [ERROR_TYPE] == "java_exception" and "throttled" not in [tags]{
    stdout {codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "logstash"
    }
    }
}
```

And nothing came up. Why does this not get throttled by the "before-count" in the throttle filter?

Any thoughts anyone?